# Prevent LED blinking on Sony Vaio

Tags: battery, vaio, sony

I own a Sony Vaio VPCSB18GG model laptop, running Ubuntu 14.04. The dedicated power button has a LED built-in. The LED glows green when the laptop is being used. But when the battery is say, 30%, it starts blinking until I plugin the power source for charging. 
It is very annoying at times because I want to connect the charges only when the battery is critically low. So, is there a way I can stop LED blinking or may be decrease the percentage of battery power upon reaching which it will start blinking?

Comment: If it's happening in both windows (which I assume it came with) and ubuntu it's likely a BIOS/UEFI setting. See if there's anything there to disable it

Comment: Yes. It happens with Windows as well. So how do I change it in BIOS settings?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd have to see your BIOS. Look around in your BIOS for something that looks related